# long int in dataframe conversion (data.matrix()) or mean() of factor value

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have this type of data.frame :

```
  "id"         "var1"    "t" "x" "y" "z" "idconnect"    "bool1"
924903565        16       64 104 133 87   940539767         1
924903564        14       64 131  95 87   940539931         1
924903563        22       64 135 248 86   924903449         1
```

but the `colMeans()` or `mean()` function doesn't work (return NA, or false value when I use the `as.numeric()` before): I tried to have the `mean(mydata[mydata[, "idconnect"]==940539931, "x"])` for example, but `class(mydata[mydata[, "idconnect"]==940539931, "x"])` return "factor". I expected matrix or vector. Why is it factor and not  here ? The as.matrix of my factor is weird.

So I tried to convert my dataframe into matrix but `sapply(..., as.numerix)` or `data.matrix()`, it returns :

```
"id"     "var1"    "t"  "x" "y" "z" "idconnect"    "bool1"
 47         7      442   5  34  97    154228          3
 46         5      442  32 395  97    154274          3
 45        14      442  36 149  96        45          3
```

How can I convert my dataframe in matrix (with the respect of my long int value) ?

Comment: To convert a factor to numeric, use `as.numeric(as.character(mydata$id)`. From the information that you give, it is impossible to say WHY these variables are factors. Did you read the data from a file with `read.table()` or `read.csv()`. Then you should use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (see `?read.table` for more information).

Comment: @Stibu I used `read.csv()` to read my data. I already tried `as.numeric(as.character())`: it didn't work. I tried your `stringsAsFactors`, but when I did `class(mydata[mydata[, "idconnect"]==940539931, "x"])` it returned "character". I don't understand what's wrong in my code. Maybe trying to apply `mean()` would be a better way to solve my problem?

Comment: That the columns has no class character indicates that `stringsAsFactors` has worked. That the columns are read as character instead of numeric means that something prevents `read.csv` to convert these columns to numeric. But this has most likely to do with your csv file and since I don't have that file, I can only speculate. And what do you mean by "it didn't work", i.e., how exaclty does it no work?